# How to navigate from App.xaml.cs to other pages?

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have different pages in my application. Since I want a menubar across all of these pages I made the following in my App.xaml.

I would normally use NavigationService to navigated between different pages.
But how do I navigate to different pages from my App.xaml.cs.

```
<Application.Resources>
        <Menu x:Key="Menu">
            <DockPanel  VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontSize="14">
                    <MenuItem Header="_File">
                        <Separator />
                        <MenuItem Header="_Exit" />
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="_Statussen" Click="MenuItem_OnClick"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="_TipsTricks" />
                </Menu>
            </DockPanel>
        </Menu>
    </Application.Resources>
```

I got pages StatussenPage.xaml etc. on menuitem click it should show that page etc.

Added following code to my App.xaml.cs:

```
        Page testpage = new TipsTricksPage();

        private void MenuItem_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            testpage.NavigationService.Navigate(new TipsTricksPage());
        }
```

And getting following error:
System.NullReferenceException

Comment: Please clarify your **specific problem** or **add additional details** to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Hille updated the question hope it's more clear now?

Comment: What error do you get? Why does this does not fit your needs? Does your main window even have a frame?

Comment: @Hille updated it with what I tried and the error i am getting.

Comment: You can't navigate on a page to a page. You need something to display the page like a frame (`myFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new TipsTricksPage());`)

Comment: @SamHaekens: What does testpage do in your example? Where are you intending to show the `TipsTricksPage` to which you are trying to navigate? You need to have a `Frame` and a `window` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In best practice, **You should start your app with a MainWindow**.

**In App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="projectname.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Banc_Suspension_SAHD"
             StartupURI="MainWindow.xaml.cs" // Right here !
             Exit="App_Exit">
```

then, IN your MainWindow (open directly when app start) you can create a Menu
and in the MainWindow.cs treat click event.

**In MainWindow.Xaml.cs**

```
<Window x:Class="projectname.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
            <Menu>
                <MenuItem Header="Re-Impression PV">
                    <MenuItem Click = "MyActionClick"></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem></MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>
            <Menu/>
      </Grid>
</Window>
```

**In MainWindow.cs**

```
        private void MyActionClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Your code
        }
```

Comment: Yes this is how I did it before.
But how do I get the menu to show over my different pages with the same Click events to the pages?

Comment: Your have your window and a frame and a menu `<window ...><menu ... /><frame ... /></window>` so the menu is not affected by any page changes

Comment: @ErosGuil may add the frame to the grid to clarify where the page should be loaded in